# Display array length dynamically

Tags: vue.js, websocket

I am trying to display websocket messages received with index and total number. How can I display total dynamically?

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn @click="clickButton">Test Websocket</v-btn>
    <h1>Total webhooks : {{total}}</h1>
    <ul v-for="(log,index) in logs" :key=index >
      <li>{{index}} - {{ log }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          logs: [],
          newlog: '',
          total:0
        }
      },
      methods: {
        clickButton: function () {
          this.$socket.send('Let me ask you a questin.can u hear me???')
        }
      },
      created () {
        this.$options.sockets.onmessage = (data) => {
          console.log(data)
          this.logs.push(data.data)
        }
      },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a computed property there. You can simply use `{{logs.length}}` in instead of total

here is a sample fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/czgnv53q/3/

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use [Computed Property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      logs: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    total() {
      return this.logs.length;
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: @AbdullaThanseeh Glad it helped. Don't forget to accept my answer :)

Comment: sure i will do that